# Making unbalanced panel balanced with missing observations

Tags: stata

I am attempting to make the data balanced for my sample. My data currently looks like:

```
id year y
1  2000 2
1  2002 4
1  2003 5
2  2001 2
2  2002 3 
....
```

And I would like it to look like:

```
id year y
1  2000 2
1  2001 .
1  2002 4
1  2003 5
2  2000 .
2  2001 2
2  2002 3 
....
```

I have tried creating a .dta of just the year and merging it to the data; however, I can't get it to work. Essentially I would like to add rows of missing data to the panel. I realize I could just drop `id`s with unbalanced data, but this is not an option for my methodology.

Comment: "rows" is spreadsheet-speak for Stata's observations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to skim the Data-Management Reference Manual [D] when looking for basic data management functionality. In this case `fillin` does what you seem to be asking.

```
clear 
input id year y
1  2000 2
1  2002 4
1  2003 5
2  2001 2
2  2002 3 
end
fillin id year 
list, sepby(id) 

     +-------------------------+
     | id   year   y   _fillin |
     |-------------------------|
  1. |  1   2000   2         0 |
  2. |  1   2001   .         1 |
  3. |  1   2002   4         0 |
  4. |  1   2003   5         0 |
     |-------------------------|
  5. |  2   2000   .         1 |
  6. |  2   2001   2         0 |
  7. |  2   2002   3         0 |
  8. |  2   2003   .         1 |
     +-------------------------+
```